# Split a returned block of text into lines in terminal?

Tags: shell, echo, newlines

When I give commands like `echo $PATH` or `which program`, I often get a very large block of text consisting of may directories. This is fairly useless, if I am for example, looking to see if there is or is not one specific path among them.

**Is there a way to split these up so that each entry starts on a new line?**

The output does not include line breaks, but I can see there are appropriate delimiter characters like `:` that I could use.

Comment: post the input and  expected output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
> echo foo:bar:baz | tr : '\n'
foo
bar
baz

> text=foo:bar:baz
> echo -e "${text//:/\n}"
foo
bar
baz
```

Comment: All the answers here are very informative! But this one is quick, and simple enough that I can see how it works without even needing to look up tr, so will be easy to remember and use for this purpose. Thanks!

Comment: How does the second solution work? I haven't seen this syntax before: `${text//:/\n}`

Comment: @MertNuhoglu See the man page, section `Parameter Expansion`, `${parameter/pattern/string}`

Answer (score 5):

With `csh`, `tcsh` or `zsh`, `$PATH` is mapped to the `$path` array, and you can print its elements one per line with:

```
printf '%s\n' $path
```

With zsh only:

```
print -rl $path
```

(here assuming the components of `$PATH` don't start with `-` and are not empty, use `print -rl -- "$path[@]"` otherwise).

With Bourne-like shells, assuming paths there don't contain wildcard characters (if they do, add `set -f;` before `printf`):

```
(IFS=:; printf '%s\n' $PATH)
```

Add some `|grep something` to search for particular strings.

If you want to search in the value of `$path`, with `zsh`, you can do:

```
vared path
```

and then use <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> as usual to search forward backward (or the `vi` `?`/`/` equivalent if you're using `vi` mode).

Answer (score 1):

Through GNU `sed`,

```
echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g'
```

Example:

```
$ echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g'
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
```

Comment: Note that that syntax is not standard. You might as well use `tr` here for character transliteration.

Comment: _Note that that syntax is not standard_, How?

Comment: The `\n` is not. The POSIX/traditional way to have a newline on the right hand side of the `s` command is with a backslash followed by an actual newline character. (also note that using `echo` and leaving $PATH unquoted might alter the value (unlikely as PATH components are usually tamed)).

Comment: backslash with the newline character displays the actual input as output no change in there.

Comment: The argument passed to `sed` must contain the backslash followed by a newline character. Beware some shell implementations (not Bourne-like ones though) treat `\<NL` specially themselves in single quotes. In `ksh93`, `bash`, `zsh`, you can write it `sed $'s/:/\\\n/g' <<< "$PATH"`